# Google DLP: "ValueError: Protocol message Value has no "stringValue" field."

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dlp

I have a method where I build a table for multiple items for Google's DLP [inspect API](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.content/inspect) which can take either a [ContentItem](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/ContentItem), or a [table](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/ContentItem#Table) of [values](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/Value)

Here is how the request is constructed:

```
def redact_text(text_list):
    dlp = google.cloud.dlp.DlpServiceClient()
    project = 'my-project'
    parent = dlp.project_path(project)
    items = build_item_table(text_list)

    info_types = [{'name': 'EMAIL_ADDRESS'}, {'name': 'PHONE_NUMBER'}]
    inspect_config = {
        'min_likelihood': "LIKELIHOOD_UNSPECIFIED",
        'include_quote': True,
        'info_types': info_types
    }
    response = dlp.inspect_content(parent, inspect_config, items)

    return response


def build_item_table(text_list):
    rows = []
    for item in text_list:
        row = {"values": [{"stringValue": item}]}
        rows.append(row)
    table = {"table": {"headers": [{"name": "something"}], "rows": rows}}
    return table
```

When I run this I get back the error `ValueError: Protocol message Value has no "stringValue" field.` Even though the [this example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/dlp/v2/dlp.projects.content.deidentify?parent=projects%252Fdlp-demo-3&_h=2&resource=%257B%250A%20%20%2522item%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522table%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522headers%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522account_no%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522comments%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522rows%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522values%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%252212AFAA567899%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%2522This%20customer%20is%20really%20happy.%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522values%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%252244E4333BB399%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%2522This%20customer%20is%20really%20sad.%20Please%20call%20them%20at%20858-333-2222%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522values%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%252212AFAA567899%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522stringValue%2522%253A%20%2522We've%20seen%20this%20customer%20before%20%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%250A%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%2522deidentifyConfig%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%2522recordTransformations%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522fieldTransformations%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522fields%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522account_no%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522primitiveTransformation%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522cryptoReplaceFfxFpeConfig%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522cryptoKey%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522transient%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522ABCD1%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522customAlphabet%2522%253A%20%25221234567890ABCDEF%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522fields%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522comments%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522infoTypeTransformations%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522transformations%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522infoTypes%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522PHONE_NUMBER%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%255D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522primitiveTransformation%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522cryptoReplaceFfxFpeConfig%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522surrogateInfoType%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name%2522%253A%20%2522%255BPHONE%255D%2522%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257D%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522customAlphabet%2522%253A%20%25221234567890-%2522%252C%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522cryptoKey%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522transient%2522%253A%20%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%257B%250A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2522name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and the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/reference/rest/v2/Value) say otherwise.

Is there something off in how I build the request?

Edit: Here's the output from `build_item_table`

```
{
    'table':
    {
        'headers': 
        [
            {'name': 'value'}
        ], 
        'rows': 
        [
            {
                'values': 
                [
                    {
                        'stringValue': 'My name is Jenny and my number is (555) 867-5309, you can also email me at anemail@gmail.com, another email you can reach me at is email@email.com.  '
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                'values': 
                [
                    {
                        'stringValue': 'Jimbob Doe (555) 111-1233, that one place down the road some_email@yahoo.com'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try string_value .... python uses the field names, not the type name.